# PHP Soap Fault "Could not connect to host"

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client

There are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318870/soapfault-exception-could-not-connect-to-host) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165142/soap-error-fatal-error-uncaught-soapfault-exception-http-could-not-connect-t?lq=1) [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410658/php-soapclient-soapfault-exception-could-not-connect-to-host) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009673/php-soap-could-not-connect-to-host) with the same problem, but any of them helped me.

Here is my code to call a Soap Web service:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
                               'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                               'trace' => 1,
                               'exceptions'=> true,
                               'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                               'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE,           
                               'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
                                ))
$params = new SoapVar($xmlString, XSD_ANYXML, null, null);
try {
    $client->functionName($params);
catch (SoapFault $f) {
    print_r ($f);
}
```

This is (part of) the SoapFault Object:

```
SoapFault Object
(
    [message:protected] => Could not connect to host
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /home/user/Documentos/Web/Client.class.php //fileName
    [line:protected] => 49 //line where I have $client->functionName
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [function] => __doRequest
                    [class] => SoapClient
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> // the XML

                            [1] => https://example.company.com/WSDLName.svc //name of WSDL
                            [2] => http://example.org/Pull/functionName //URL with name of the function
                            [3] => 1
                            [4] => 0
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/user/Documentos/Web/Client.class.php //fileName
                    [line] => 49
                    [function] => __call
                    [class] => SoapClient
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => functionName
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => SoapVar Object
                                        (
                                            [enc_type] => 147
                                            [enc_value] => //the XML
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )
```

If I call `print_r($client->__getLastRequest());` and test the printed XML in [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) all works like a charm.

If I call `print_r(file_get_contents($wsdl));` I got the WSDL file.

Trying `var_dump($client->__getLastRequestHeaders())`, getting `null`;

**My attempts until now:**

1) Putting a `ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);` just before the line `$client = new SoapClient...`. Same error.

2) Changes the call line to `$client->__soapCall('functionName',(array)$params)`. Same error. The only difference is the XML formatted with `&lt;` and `&#13;`.

3) Change my soap options just to `array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,'trace' => 1)`. Same error.

4) The wsdl URL is a http URL, so I believe that is not a SSL problem. However, in the SoapFault object, I receive the same URL with https, so I changed my $wsdl to the URL with https:// and receive the error `SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://example.company.com/WSDLName.svc?wsdl'`.

As I said, all works fine in SoapUI.

Finally, here is my server info:

> Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
>
> Apache 2.4.7
>
> PHP 5.5.9

Someone has any idea on what I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Following the comments below, here are more information:

1) Both `http` and `https` URLs in the browser returns the WSDL document.

2) If I ping the wsdl URL in terminal, I receive `ping: unknown host https://example.org/Pull/functionName`. The WSDL also has a method named Ping, defined as:

```
<wsdl:operation name="Ping">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IPull/Ping" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

When I use it in PHP I got the same scenario: A Soap Fault "Could not connect to host", but the XML created works fine in SoapUI.

3) The result of `var_dump($client)` is:

```
object(SoapClient)[42]
  public 'trace' => int 1
  public 'compression' => int 32
  public '_encoding' => string 'UTF-8' (length=5)
  public '_soap_version' => int 1
  public 'sdl' => resource(30, Unknown)
```

***Note***: I got a workaround to deal with the problem that is definitively not the best option, but works. 
I created the whole XML body (inclusing the soap envelope) using `DOMDocument` or `SimpleXML` and send it via [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to the URL `https://example.company.com/WSDLName.svc`.
It's ugly, but works to me for the moment while I'm waiting for any other solution.

Comment: Why don't you pump those URLs in a browser and see what you get?

Comment: did you try to ping the enpoint URL in your WSDL?

Comment: @AaronGong. Both `http` and `https` URLs in the browser returns the WSDL document.

Comment: try var_dump($client); after assignment, what do you get?

Comment: @Linh. See my update. I don't know if I understood your advice, but I tried to ping the WSDL in two different forms.

Comment: @AaronGong. I put the result of `var_dump` in my update, too.

Comment: maybe you can compare what CURL spits out with the SoapClient

Comment: @AaronGong. How can I do it?

Comment: Use the browser debug console or firebug (for firefox), since the protocol for the request is http/https, I think you can view what request you are sending out...